# side by side plot in RMarkdown pdf template

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, r-markdown

I have stupid RMarkdown issue :

I would like to put 2 plot side by side in a pdf output :

````
```{r  echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.pos = 'H', fig.cap="\\label{fig:myplot} my fig"}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(rnorm(100))
plot(rnorm(100))

```
````

That is working as expected :

[image]

But if I call 2 plot generated via `ggplot2` from a shiny app and do the same :

````
```{r  echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, out.width="50%", fig.pos = 'H', fig.cap="\\label{fig:windplot} my fig"}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 params$plot_month
 params$plot_hour
```
````

The result is different (regardless of `out.width` command) :

[image]

Adding `fig.show="hold"` will correct the alignment but I loose the figure caption !!!

[image]

Any idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: There are some packages for displaying multiple ggplots with a desired layout. There is **cowplot** and another one, I forgot its name. `par(mfrow` is for base plots only.

Comment: The other one that @StéphaneLaurent may be thinking of is [`patchwork`](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=patchwork) which is easy to use and build for, among other things, just this.  See its documentation, or may answers here.  (Another, older school, trick I used is to created to png or jpeg files and use latex's `\includegraphics` to place them side by side.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `plot_grid` function of the **cowplot** package to create a grid of 'ggplots':

```r
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10, y1 = 1:10, y2 = (1:10)^2
)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point()

plot_grid(p1, p2, align = "h")
```

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html) are other ressources.

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent, thanks for the reply, what if at the end of `ggplot` I use the `ggplotly` , then your proposed solution is return a warning and blank plot: 
`Warning in as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class plotlyhtmlwidget into a grob.`

Comment: @user9112767 You can use the **combineWidgets** package to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to switch to quarto, you could use the `layout-ncol: 2` functionality. Using Stéphane's example data:

````
---
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| layout-valign: bottom
#| fig-subcap: 
#|   - "First Plot"
#|   - "Second Plot"
#| layout-ncol: 2

library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10, y1 = 1:10, y2 = (1:10)^2
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point()
ggplot(df, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point()
```
````

[image]